# Play 2 Framework - SSL Certificates from a keystore

Tags: configuration, playframework, playframework-2.0, ssl-certificate

I am trying to configure a key store in the Play server.

I was able to do this sucessfuly by define command line paramters **Dhttps.keyStore** and **https.keyStorePassword** as shown below.

```
... -Dhttps.keyStore="C:/tempKS/myserver.jks" -Dhttps.keyStorePassword="xxxxx" ...
```

My question is how to define these two properties in the application.conf instead of passing as parameters at the command line.

I tried this in the application.conf but server didn't pick those values.

```
https.keyStore="C:/tempKS/myserver.jks"
https.keyStorePassword="xxxxx"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at https://github.com/typesafehub/activator-play-tls-example/blob/master/app/https/CustomSSLEngineProvider.scala and set it to read from the application's Configuration object.